# WatchKit Complication Modular Large Columns - width of columns

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch-complication

I have no idea how to **adjust columns width in CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeColumns template**.

I always end up with ellipsis in second column.

How to fix the layout so second column would be readable?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that this is a **bug in simulator**.

The same app works correctly on real device.

Comment: Reset content and settings ... Option in simulator menu seems to fix the issue